# Error reading plugin heroku-git. Reinstalling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I used to use heroku command line gem but now I decided to install the Heroku Toolbelt on Mac OSX. So now when I run heroku command this line appear: 
    `heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...Error reading plugin heroku-git.     Reinstalling...`

So if someone have the same problem and resoved it please help me!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found an answer, I deleted all the heroku installation that I had , and reinstall the Heroku Toolbelt , and now it works nice.

I deleted the 
    '~/.heroku' 
directory and the 
    'heroku' binary.